# I2C line dropping voltage before making call to slave

Tags: arduino, voltage, stm32, i2c

I have been coding an stm32f3discovery to talk to the arduino nano as part of my project for building a drone. I have had it working before but have since made my own pcb for it all to link into and now the two won't talk to each other. After linking it up to an oscilliscope I can see that the voltage seems to drop off before then making the call to the slave (arduino) if I unplug the board it works fine and the signal looks as it should. It also does the same thing when talking to the accelerometer built into the stm32f3discovery.

In this call it is trying to call the number 30 (001_1110)

**DATA LINE**

This is what it looks like:
[image: Data line]
And this is what it looks when it is zoomed in. The fact that you can see the clock lines in the signal line is something I have often come accross with arduino and it hasn't caused an issue before
[image]

**CLOCK LINE**
[image: Clock line]

[image: Clock line zoomed in]

To me this feels like a wiring issue but I am very new to all of this so may be completely off. This is also the link to the pcb. I have now linked both up to the one power source

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvQFsm9Fi805gacTSmSaViNqiqsV6A?e=6cz4R1

Comment: Could you link your schematics? It will help a lot answering your question.

Comment: Do you have a pull-up resistor? You should not be able to see the clock in the signal like that, no matter what.

Comment: @Ananas_hoi, Apologies, it was saved on the windows side of my machine so was trying to get over there before anyone saw the question. Should be there for you now

Comment: I can't seem to find any I2C pull-ups. Are you sure they are in place (either internal pull-up or external) it doesn't really seem to correlate with what your scope shows but who knows

Comment: That link is unusable. On a phone it requires login. On a computer, there's only gerber files. Would it be possible to have a PDF of the schematics?

Comment: There may be a missing ground connection or pullup resistors. Please provide a schematic, not (only) your layout.

Comment: The second image looks like you have two drivers driving against each other. Are both I2C sides configured as master? Could it be that the pins of one side are not configured correctly?

Comment: For schematics of the i2c connection there is just two direct lines from the stm32f3discovery to the arduino. After reading your comments I have looked into what a pull up/down resistor is and that does feel like it could be that. Does that mean I would need a pull up resistor as i2c idle is high?